# Parameterized Jenkins builds: ignore if param is missing

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am testing an API and I have some Parameterized Jenkins builds.

For some tests, (I will call Test One) I wish to choose the environment and port number

For others, (I will call Test Two) I want to choose the environment, port number and some search string parameters (for context, star rating of holidays).

I am running using TestNG. I have simplified the problem to explain:

Test One TestNG Suite.XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">

<parameter name="testName" value="Test 1"/>
<parameter name="description" value="some stuff"/>

<test name="test1">

    <!--SERVER AND TARGET PARAMS-->
    <parameter name="environment" value="${environment}"/>
    <parameter name="port" value="${port}"/>

    <parameter name="currency" value="GBP"/>

    <!--tests to run-->
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.abc.api.TestOne"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

Test Two TestNG suite xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">

<parameter name="testName" value="Test 2"/>
<parameter name="description" value="some stuff"/>

<test name="test2">

    <!--SERVER AND TARGET PARAMS-->
    <parameter name="environment" value="${environment}"/>
    <parameter name="port" value="${port}"/>

    <!--Searching Parameters-->
    <parameter name="starRatingOne" value="${starRatingOne}"/>
     <parameter name="starRatingTwo" value="${starRatingTwo}"/>

    <parameter name="currency" value="GBP"/>

    <!--tests to run-->
    <classes>
        <class name="com.mycompany.abc.api.TestTwo"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

My POM file snippet:

```
<groupId>co.uk.mycompanytest.project</groupId>
<artifactId>super-api-automation</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <sl4j.version>1.7.7</sl4j.version>
    <suiteFile>${suiteFile}</suiteFile>
    <environment>${environment}</environment>
    <port>${port}</port>
    <starRatingOne>${starRatingOne}</starRatingOne>
    <starRatingTwo>${starRatingTwo}</starRatingTwo>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory</name>
                            <value>org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>user.language</name>
                        <value>en</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
                <!--<testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>-->
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>${environment}</environment>
                    <environment>${port}</environment>
                    <starRatingOne>${starRatingOne}</starRatingOne>
                    <starRatingTwo>${starRatingTwo}</starRatingTwo>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>parallel</name>
                        <value>methods</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>threadCount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                        <value>1</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My Two Jenkins Jobs are parameterized builds so testers can pass in params at will:-

**Test One:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**Test Two:**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The Maven Goal in the Jenkins job for TestOne is:

```
  clean test -DsuiteFile="src/test/resources/suites/testng_testOne.xml" -Denvironment=$environment -Dport=$port -DstarRatingOne=$starRatingOne -DstarRatingTwo=$starRatingTwo
```

And Test Two:

```
clean test -DsuiteFile="src/test/resources/suites/testng_testOne.xml" -Denvironment=$environment -Dport=$port
```

The error I receive for Job two is, of course:-

```
Parsing POMs
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were     encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Resolving expression: '${starRatingOne}': Detected the following     recursive expression cycle in 'starRatingOne': [starRatingOne] @ 
[ERROR] Resolving expression: '${starRatingTwo}': Detected the following     recursive expression cycle in 'starRatingTwo': [starRatingTwo] @
```

Essentially what I need to know is: How can I have separate Jenkins jobs with different numbers of params required but only one POM file?  I guess I need the jobs that don't have matching params being passed in the maven goal to be ignored or have default values.  So where no starRatingOne param is found, then don't try and use it (maybe the API request for that job won't expect to be asked for a star rating).

- I'm not sure I explained the situation well
- I'm not clear I'm approaching the issue the best way

Any help appreciated